# GitHub Workflow Prettier

Tags: github, github-actions, prettier

Hoping someone can help or provide guidance.  I am have been bashing my head trying to a GitHub Workflow to run Prettier against all the files that have been added / modified in a pull request, and then commit them back the pull request.  I have managed to get the below going so far, but hitting an error when trying to commit the changes back to the PR.

I am new to all this so could be going about it all wrong and just cannot find a example to reference, which makes me think I am doing something wrong :)

```
name: Pull Request Workflow
on:
    pull_request:
        types: [opened, reopened, edited, synchronize]
jobs:
    lint-analyse-code:
        name: Lint & Analyse Code
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        steps:
            - name: Step 1 - Checkout Repository
              uses: actions/checkout@v3
            
            - name: Step 2 - Setup GIT 
              run: |
                  echo "BRANCHES"
                  git branch -v
                  echo "REMOTES"
                  git remote -v
                  echo "GITHUB_REF is $GITHUB_REF"
                  echo "GITHUB_HEAD_REF is $GITHUB_HEAD_REF"
                  echo "GITHUB_BASE_REF is $GITHUB_BASE_REF"
                  git config advice.ignoredHook false

            - name: Step 3 - Setup Node.js
              uses: actions/setup-node@v3

            - name: Step 4 - Install NPM Dependencies
              run: npm install

            - name: Step 5 - Get Changed Files
              id: changed-files
              uses: tj-actions/changed-files@v29.0.7 
              with:
                since_last_remote_commit: true

            - name: Step 6 - Prettier
              run: npm run prettier-npx ${{ steps.changed-files.outputs.all_changed_files }}

            - name: Step 7 - Commit Changes
              run: | 
                echo HEAD:$GITHUB_HEAD_REF
                git config user.email "devops@blahblah.co.za" 
                git config user.name "DevOps"
                git add .
                git commit -m "Automatically Applied Prettier [skip actions]" || echo "Nothing to push"
                git push origin HEAD:$GITHUB_HEAD_REF
```

Error Message
[image]